# Laravel 5: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a simple Article Model and a User Model.

Article "belongsTo" a User and a User "hasMany" Article.

Therefore my article migration has a foreign key called "user_id".

```
    Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Yet whenever I create an Article where I pass the "user_id" in a hidden field I get an error message.

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'articles.store')) !!}

    {!! Form::hidden('userId', $user->id) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}         
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('text', 'Write your Article') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('text', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}          
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Create Article', array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-success')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the error message. And I understand that I doesn't try to insert the value for the 'user_id' into the articles table.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tags`.`articles`,
>   CONSTRAINT `articles_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
>   REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`,
>   `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Title, Some text,
>   2015-03-21 23:19:33, 2015-03-21 23:19:33))

Here is my Store Method on my AriclesController:

```
    Article::create([
        'title'   => Input::get('title'),
        'body'    => Input::get('text'),
        'user_id' => Input::get('userId')
    ]);

    return Redirect::to('articles');
```

There are dozens of other open Stackoverflow Questions with a similar title, and I am searching yet unsuccessfully for the answer that fits my specific case, therefore I thank you in advance kind stranger.

How do I save an article into my database?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Make sure you have `user_id` in the `fillable` property of your Article model.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Thank you Adam. Can't believe I forgot to put the 'user_id' in the fillable array.

Comment: You should watch out when adding 'user_id' to the fillable array since in some cases it allows a user to change the owner of the model when you don't want to allow that

Comment: God bless you Adam.

Answer (score 40):

I had the same problem. I added a foreign key to a table that already existed and had data and I couldn't run the migrations because it kept failing.
The solution to make the migration work was to make the foreign key nullable.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();

// then the foreign key
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Hoping it saves someone else time in the future.

Comment: I had three tables: users, products, product_user (a pivot table). I was getting "Cannot update or delete a parent row" when I tried to delete one of products which was referenced in the pivot. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: I had products and categories table related. First I had forgotten to create the foreign key relationship. $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned() threw error but then your solution worked. I guess this was a mysql issue.

Answer (score 9):

I have faced this error a couple times when running migration for existing table. The cause were any of below:

1. the type of 'user_id' and users 'id' is different.
   for example when 'user_id' is INT and users 'id' is BIGINT.
2. the column 'user_id' is not empty, you need to makeit nullable
3. there are values in column 'user_id' that do not exist in users 'id'

Comment: For me it was the 3rd option: I added a foreign key column to table A that used the default value 0, but as the referenced table B was empty, 0 was not a valid value. So I set the foreign key column to nullable :`$table->unsignedBigInteger('B_table_id')->nullable();`

Comment: Update to my comment above: A better solution was to clear the data from table A then I was able to avoid using `nullable()`.

Answer (score 3):

For me what worked was by adding `nullable()` also with Laravel 7+ you can do `foreignId` so for your case

`$table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();`

And for the rollback
 `$table->dropForeign(['user_id']);` and then
 `$table->dropColumn('user_id');`

Also if data exist we don't want to pull it down in production so you can disable foreign key constraints

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreign('user_id')
   ->references('id')->on('users')
   ->onDelete('cascade');
  });
 Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Comment: I was stuck for 1 hour. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue, since I was updating an existing table, with existing data, hence adding a foreign key was causing an issue since there was no default foreign key to assign to the entries. I solved this by first removing data from the table, then running the migration afresh

Answer (score 0):

in my case (laravel 7 ) need to add nullable when creating the column,
and also add ->nullable()->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete() when creating the foreign, in addition it includes DB transaction because the new table was being created before the error happened, and I always needed to drop it before running the migrate

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CreateUnidadePesoTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();
            Schema::create('unidades_peso', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('unidade',3);
                $table->string('descricao',20);
                $table->timestamps();
            });

            //relacionamento com a tabela produto 1 para muitos
            Schema::table('produtos', function (Blueprint $table){
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('unidade_peso_id')->nullable();
                $table->foreign('unidade_peso_id')->references('id')->on('unidades_peso')->nullable()->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            });
                
            //relacionamento com a tabela produto_detalhes 1 para muitos
            Schema::table('produto_detalhes', function (Blueprint $table){
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('unidade_peso_id')->nullable();
                $table->foreign('unidade_peso_id')->references('id')->on('unidades_peso')->nullable()->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            });
            DB::commit();
        }catch (Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();
            //--remover relacionamento com produto_detalhes
            Schema::table('produto_detalhes', function (Blueprint $table){
                // remover a fk primeiro
                $table->dropForeign('produto_detalhes_unidade_peso_id_foreign');// [table]_[coluna]_[foreign]
                //remover a coluna unidade_id
                $table->dropColumn('unidade_peso_id');
                
            });

            

            //--remover relacionamento com produtos
            Schema::table('produtos', function (Blueprint $table){
                // remover a fk primeiro
                $table->dropForeign('produtos_unidade_peso_id_foreign');// [table]_[coluna]_[foreign]
                //remover a coluna unidade_id
                $table->dropColumn('unidade_peso_id');
                
            });

            Schema::dropIfExists('unidades_peso');
            DB::commit();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I needed to do to solve this - and the only thing that did solve it after a few hours of being unable to run a simple `php artisan migrate` - was to wrap everything in my `up()` function inside of `disableForeignKeyConstraints()` and `enableForeignKeyConstraints()`. Making use of the `up()` function is necessary to ensure you don't see any redundant constraint errors each time you need to run your migrations with `php artisan migrate`.

```
public function up() {
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('title');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
    // Your migration setup code here
    // ...
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```