# Laravel insert records (foreign key)

Tags: laravel, insert, foreign-keys

When I trying add new record to database Laravel returned error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`kurwa_magazyn`.`transmits`, CONSTRAINT
>   `transmits_to_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`to_user_id`) REFERENCES
>   `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `transmits` (`from_user_id`,
>   `to_user_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `transmit`, `created_at`,
>   `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2016-08-16 18:08:53,
>   2016-08-16 18:08:53, 1))

```
    $transmit = new transmit($request->all());
    $transmit['from_user_id'] = $idKey;
    $transmit['to_user_id'] = $idKey2;
    $transmit['product_id'] = $downloadProductsId;
    $transmit['quantity'] = $downloadIlosc;
    $transmit['transmit'] = 0;
    $transmit['created_at'] = $dateNow;
    $transmit['updated_at'] = $dateNow;

    Auth::user()->transmits()->save($transmit);
    //Session::flash('status1', 'Artykuł został dodany poprawnie');
    return redirect('warehouse');
```

But when I trying add only ONE value, for example `$transmit['to_user_id'] = $idKey2;` then everything works correctly:

```
$transmit = new transmit($request->all());
$transmit['to_user_id'] = $idKey2;
Auth::user()->transmits()->save($transmit);
return redirect('warehouse');
```

my file model transmit.php:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'user_id',
    'from_user_id',
    'to_user_id',
    'product_id',
    'quantity',
    'transmit',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
];
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

And file add new record (transferProductUser.php):

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    {!! Form::model(['method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal','action'=>['TransmitsController@updateTransferProduct']]) !!}


                Produkt:
                <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" data-live-search="true" data-size="5" name="products" id="products" onchange="copy()">
                  <option selected disabled style="color: orange">Wybierz...</option>
                @foreach( $listProductOfSelectedUser as $listProduct)
                  <option data-subtext="(
                    <?php
                    $sn = DB::table('products')->select('sn')->where('id', '=', $listProduct->product_id)->get();
                    $quantity = DB::table($name_user)->select('quantity')->where('product_id', '=', $listProduct->product_id)->get();
                    ?>
                    @foreach($sn as $serial)
                        @if($serial->sn == '')
                            <i>~brak SN~</i>
                        @elseif($serial->sn)
                            {{ $serial->sn }}
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                    @foreach($quantity as $ilosc)
                            ) ilość: <b>{{ $ilosc->quantity }} szt.</b>
                    @endforeach

                  " value="{{ $listProduct->product_id }}">

                        <?php
                        $article_name = DB::table('products')->select('article_id')->where('id', '=', $listProduct->product_id)->get();
                        ?>
                        @foreach ($article_name as $name) 
                            {{ article::find($name->article_id)->article_name }}
                        @endforeach

                   </option>
                @endforeach
                </select>

                <br />

                Do:
                <select name="stan2" id="stan2" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" data-size="5" onchange="run2(event)">
                <option selected disabled>Wybierz...</option>
                  <optgroup id="użytkownicy" value="użytkownicy" label="użytkownicy">
                    @foreach($userListName as $user)
                        <option name="użytkownicy" value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </optgroup>

                  <optgroup id="magazyny" value="magazyny" label="magazyny">

                    @foreach($warehouseList as $warehouse)
                        <option name="magazyny" value="{{ $warehouse->id }}">{{ $warehouse->name_warehouse }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </optgroup>
                </select>



              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"> Podaj ilość produktów do przeniesienia.
                </label>
              </div>

            <input type="number" class='form-control', id="txtAge" name="count" id="txtAge" style="display:none" min='0', max="", placeholder='Podaj ilość produktow do przeniesienia...'>



            <br />

            {!! Form::text('stan_key', 'user,'.$userId, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'copy']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('stan_key2', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'copy3']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('idProduct', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'copy2']) !!}

            {!! Form::submit('Tak, przenieś', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            {!! link_to('warehouse', $title = 'Anuluj', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}

</div>


<script>

function run2(event) {
console.log(document.getElementById("użytkownicy").label);
var $id = document.getElementById("stan2").value;
var lable=event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].parentNode.label

    if(lable == 'użytkownicy'){

      document.getElementById("copy3").value = "user,"+$id;

    } else if (lable == 'magazyny') {

      document.getElementById("copy3").value = "warehouse,"+$id;
    }

}


document.getElementById('products').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('copy2').value = event.target.value  
}


//wyswietlenie inputa z quantity
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function() {
    $("#txtAge").toggle(this.checked);
});

</script>
```

**Why can't I add all the values at once ??**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189311/laravel-5-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row)

Comment: i hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189311/laravel-5-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you are trying to

```
$transmit['to_user_id'] = $idKey2;
```

Your $idKey contains null or 0.

If you want to have a possibility to set null values, you should make this column nullable.