# A foreign key constraint fails in laravel when i make a primary key entry and asign a foreign key entry to the primery key in the same function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a blog application in Laravel in which i want to save a post with photos to the database. but every time when i try to do this it gives: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`photos`, CONSTRAINT `photos_post_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `photos` (`name`, `size`, `post_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test.jpg, 298.21 KB, 5, 2019-01-16 22:47:52, 2019-01-16 22:47:52))". The photos table is linked to the post table with a foreign key. It works when i don't assign the foreign key.

This is the code in my controller:

```
public function storePost(Request $request){

$id = Auth::user()->id;

$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->title;
$post->intro = $request->intro;
$post->text = $request->text;
$post->user_id = $id;
$post->save();
Mail::send(new SendMail());



if ($request->hasFile('file')){
  $amount;

  // try {

    foreach ($request->file as $file) {
      $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $bytes = $file->getClientSize();

      $file->storeAs('public/upload', $name);

      //convert size to a readable format

      $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');
      $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
      $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024));
      $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1);
      $bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);
      $size = round($bytes, 2) . ' ' . $units[$pow];

      $post = Post::where('title', $request->title)->first();

      $post_id = $post->id;

      $photos = new Photo;
      $photos->name = $name;
      $photos->size = $size;
      $photos->post_id = 5;
      $photos->save();
      global $amount;
      $amount = $amount. ", " .$name;


    }

  // } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
  //   $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
  //   global $amount;
  //   global $postUpload;
  //
  //   if($errorCode == 1062){
  //     return view('errors/basicError', ['error' => 'Duplicate entry error. Photos that succeeded: ' . $amount ]);
  //   }
  // }
}

return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

Dit is the code in my posts migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('intro');
        $table->text('text');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
}
}
```

This is the code in my photos migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePhotosTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('photos');

}
}
```

Comment: Your migrations don't indicate any foreign keys being created between the tables. Where are you setting that up? The error says that `photos.post_id` is referencing the `users.id` column, NOT `posts.id`. So your foreign key setup process is likely the issue.

Comment: You didn't show your models, but check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29189424/3226121). Also, once you insert the post, there is no need to fetch the values again from database. So you could remove this `$post = Post::where('title', $request->title)->first();`

Comment: And also, avoid using globals, specifically `global $amount;`